# How to SELECT only few rows from a column in sql (SQLite Database Browser)?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, browser

I am using SQLite Database Browser.

Table : Test 
Test has a single column "Words" with some values as shown below :

```
   Words
   --------
   apple
   pen
   xerox
   notebook
   toys
   zoo
   stars
   apes
```

Write an sql query (which should execute in SQLite Database Browser) to select words between 'xerox' and 'stars' & words from 'pen' up to apes.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What have you tried so far? What isn't working?

Comment: StackOverflow is [not here to do your homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework). You must put in some initial effort, clearly describe what you have tried and how the result differs from your expectations, and outline your own ideas for solutions.

Comment: I have executed "select * from Test where Words between 'apple' and 'apes'" it returns 0 rows which is natural, But I want to select words after apple and before apes i.e. pen, xerox, notebook, toys, zoo, stars.

Comment: What do you mean with "between"? Alphabetically? Please note that SQL tables do not have *any* predefined order.

Comment: @CL Sorry I was not clear. I mean Row wise not alphabetically.

Comment: What do you mean with "row wise"? In SQL, rows do *not* have an implicit identity; you can identify rows only by the values stored in them. So what is the criteria that specifies that the row containing "stars" comes after (or before) the row containing "zoo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be one option:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
         WHERE ROWID BETWEEN
                             (SELECT ROWID FROM test WHERE words = 'xerox') + 1 
                     AND
                             (SELECT ROWID FROM test WHERE words = 'stars') - 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT '---'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM test
         WHERE ROWID BETWEEN
                             (SELECT ROWID FROM test WHERE words = 'pen')
                     AND
                             (SELECT ROWID FROM test WHERE words = 'apes');
```

Comment: Thanks josepn, That's exactly what I wanted. I made a confusion by using word "between" in my 1st part of question. However I got answers of both questions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    Test
where   Words between 'stars' and 'xerox'
        or Words between 'apes' and 'pen'
```

Note that the first argument to `between` should be smaller than the second.  So `'stars'` comes before 'xerox'`because`s`comes before`x` in the alphabet.

Comment: If I execute select * from Test where Words between 'apple' and 'apes'     it returns 0 rows which is natural, But I want to select words after apple and before apes i.e. pen, xerox, notebook, toys, zoo, stars.

Comment: That's right, since `app` comes after `ape`, there can never be anything between them.  SQL tables are **unordered** sets.  Without an `order by`, a query like `select * from tables` can return rows in different order each time you run it.